# Simple space-filling curve

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Here are six iterations of [Hilbert space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).
[image]

Isn't there a simpler space-filling curve?

For example $16$ iterations of this curve:

[image]

> Isn't it also a space-filling curve?
>
> 1. If **it is not** then why?
> 2. If **it is** then why they (mathematicians) did not use the simplest possible curve? Or what are advantages of Hilbert curve over mine?

Comment: [3blue1brown](https://youtu.be/3s7h2MHQtxc) has compared these two exact curves.

Comment: Ohhh... that video explains it perfectly :-) Just start video at 6:05.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The images you provided don't lead to the construction of a space-filling curve. This is due to the fact that if you take $\{f_n\}$ to be the sequence of functions defining the iterations that you have provided, normally we'd call $f:= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n$ our resulting space-filling curve. However, in this case this limit doesn't exist (so $f$ isn't well-defined).

Comment: Specifically, it's impossible to tell what the vertical coordinate of $f(t)$ would be for any $t$.

Comment: (Well... For _most_ $t$, at least.)